# Как идентифицировать пользователя в ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core

Изучаю ASP.NET Core, делаю абстрактную многопользовательскую игру. Мне нужно как-то идентифицироваться пользователей, которые создают комнату или подключаются к ней добавляя записи в бд через EntityFramework.
Что мне присваивать для `User.Id`, если не использовать аутентификацию? Я так понимаю, что нужно смотреть в сторону сессий

Comment: пользователь пришел - поставил ему в куки сгенерированный гуид и работаешь с ней.

Comment: @SultanovShamil, спасибо! А не подскажите, как отслеживать отсоединившихся пользователей, которые ушли во время игры?

Comment: Надо сперва придумать способ, как определить что пользователь ушел и отправить на сервер событие. Например если закрыли браузер или еще что-то то кодом этого не сделать. имхо самое простое - это открывать соединения через WebSocket и использовать его. Соответственно куки уже не нужны. Пользователь ушел - если соединение было разорвано.